# Prove that $\alpha(t)$ lies on a sphere given that $\alpha(t)-a$ is orthogonal to T(t)

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a regular curve. Suppose there is a point a in R^3 such that $\alpha(t)-a$ is orthogonal to T(t) for all t. Prove that $\alpha(t)$ lies on a sphere.

So we know

$<\alpha(t)$ - a, T(t) > $= 0$

and so it follows that

$(\alpha(t)$ - a) ($\alpha'(t)) =0$

But where do I proceed?

Comment: You are missing some context. Whats $T(t)$? Say $T(t)=(1,0,0)$, $a=0$ and $\alpha(t)=(0,1,0)$. This would satisfy all your conditions. Also, please look up Mathjax, to format your equations.

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N79rK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the distance between the curve $\alpha(t)$ and $a$ squared, this is calculated by the following inner product $\langle\alpha(t)-a,\alpha(t)-a\rangle$. If this inner product was a constant you could say that the curve $\alpha$ is in the "set of points which are always at the same distance of $a$".

Of course this is possible because

$$\langle\alpha(t)-a,\alpha(t)-a\rangle' = 2\langle\alpha(t)-a,\alpha'(t)\rangle = 0, \quad \forall t \in I$$

So the distance between $\alpha$ and $a$ is a certain constant value $r$.

Comment: How does the curve being the same distance from "a" prove it lies on a sphere? Wouldnt that only be true if a=the center?

Comment: You have to show that the curve is in a certain sphere, if you prove that it is on a sphere whose center is "a" you completed the proof.It would be different if they wanted you to show it is in a particular one, surely that is not the problem we are to solve here.

Comment: To emphasize, the original problem could have been more explicit by asking you to show that the curve lies on a sphere centered at the given point $a$.

Comment: ok thanks guys!